# Correct Objective-C class naming method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

how should I call a class for a timeline custom view? My project's prefix is `HM`.

```
HMTimelineView
```

or

```
HMTimeline
```

Shouldn't I name any view class with the suffix `View`? But why is it `NSButton` but `NSImage**View**`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, HMTimeline sounds like it could be a model object, so I would recommend the "View" suffix, but this is a decision you'll have to make based on what you think makes your code easier to understand.

There may be naming rules regarding this that I'm not aware of, but I believe NSButton isn't called NSButtonView because a button is intrinsically a client-visible interface object--it   doesn't present a specific model object and is unlikely to be confused for a model object, so it's convenient to leave off the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

If you object is just a view, then you can put view on the end of it. The difference in `NSButton` and `NSImageView` are because an `NSButton` has a view, it itself is not a just a view, it is a button :P. `NSImageView` is the view of the image, it has an image, but is the object to view the image.

There also isn't a "correct" way. Using `HMTimeline` by comparison to `HMTimelineView` will not break your code. Its just a way to help a developer understand what the object is.

Comment: Didn't say that NSButton doesn't inherit from NSView. I said its a button, not a button view

Comment: The term "view" has a specific meaning in terms of Cocoa development (i.e., it's a descendent of NSView). Therefore, it's not accurate to say NSButton isn't a view. I think what you meant to say is that NSButton's sole purpose isn't to display a specific model object, like how NSImageView presents an NSImage.

Comment: added the words "just a" to clarify since this is apparently so confusing

Answer (score 1):

if it is inherited from UIView

then

```
     HMTimelineView will be best
```

if it is inherited from NSObject

then

```
      HMTimeline will be best.
```

u have to understand that

whenever anyone go to use urCustom objects like HMTimelineView,HMTimeline then then they will automatically come to know

```
   "oh it would be from View" -for HMTimelineView.

   "oh it would be from NSObject" -for HMTimeline.
```

Answer (score 1):

The “View” suffix is used inconsistently in Cocoa. Generally speaking, `NSControl` and its public subclasses don’t use “View”, but there are some inconsistencies (like `NSText`). In general, a view that presents content (which I assume a “timeline view” does) should have a “View” suffix.

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on your preferences, I guess, and understandability of the whole set of class names that make up your app. Much also depends on conventions that you will simply learn by looking at how other code is written, mostly the same SDK.

I think that `HMTimelineView` is far more understandable than `HMTimeline`. You also have to think that possibly you will have a `HMTimeLineViewController`, so `HMTimeLime` would be possibly ambiguous. Think of this, if you want: views, controllers, and models play a role in a design pattern (MVC) so that it is useful to identify them with a suffix. The same can be said for delegate classes, where the suffix is also usual.

About `NSButton`, it certainly derives from `NSView`, but its direct class is `NSButton`; so, in a sense, I think that its "control nature" prevails on the view nature, and `NSButton` is far more understandable then `UIButtonView`.

Hope this helps.